# How 0.1 capacitor diverts electrical noise on the 5v PWS line to 0V?

Tags: microcontroller

I'm not sure how one can prevent electrical noise coming from the power supply from affecting the 0V line. Could one please explain why we have to use a capacitor for that purpose?

[image]

Comment: I think you got a slightly distorted message. The capacitor makes sure that the 0v / V+ voltage seen by the F84 is stamble, by acting as a buffer (reservoir). Whether it affects the 0V *line* (to the PSU) is not visble to the F84. (PS: if you are thinking about using a 16F84, please consider a more modern chip. A 16F648A is close to an F84 and much cheaper, and even that chip is nearly obsolete.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the function of the capacitor two ways:

- It provides a very small local "backup" to the power supply to provide power to the chip during transients *caused by the chip*. This might happen, for example, each time a transistor gate switches from one state to another. These capacitors are usually connected right at the chip and are, therefore, much closer than the power supply which has resistance and some combination of inductance and capacitance on the wiring and PCB traces in between.
- The second function is to filter out noise caused by *other devices* in the circuit. Again this is usually caused by switching in those devices and a high-frequency pulse or noise can appear on the power rails. A small capacitor - typically 100 nF or 0.1 uF as shown in your schematic - is adequate in most cases to shunt the noise to ground while holding the DC steady.

Finally, it's not to protect the 0 V line in particular but to keep the 0 V and 5 V (in this case) line 5 V apart and with minimum noise.

Comment: Hi @transistor, I think that this type of capacitor is called decoupling cap, which exists in almost every chip. May you please explain why it has to be connected as close to the chip as possible? I think it has something to do with power supply delays during chip's demands for power. The second question I have is as to how it can send noise away to the ground. How could it do that?

Comment: (1) Yes it is a decoupling cap. (2) No, capacitors are difficult to fabricate in chips. There are usually none or very low values for oscillators but not for decoupling. That's why we have to add them. (3) As close to the chip as possible to have maximum effect. (4) A short voltage spike may have significant voltage but if the capacitor is big enough (and 100 nF usually is) it can absorb the voltage and hold the voltage much more steady. In that way the spike current disappears. It's "shunted to ground" in that it has disappeared into the capacitor and no longer affects the V+ line.

Comment: That's right. Also I didn't mean they are put inside the chip. I  know we add them right at the chip. But I am still not sure why, for example, a short voltage spike will be seen only by the capacitor and not the V+ line. How can the cap absorb the noise just before the V+ line could see it? @transistor

Comment: Have a read of Wikipedia's [Decoupling Capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor) article which explains it fairly well. I might do a sketch later and add it to my post. In the meantime ask again if the article raises more questions.